How to add cv_bridge package to ros2 package list?
I build the Ros 2 humble with the binary archive. And I try to add the package (e.g. cv_bridge) to the package list.
First, I cloned the source code using git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv.git -b humble and build it with colcon build --packages-select cv_bridge. The result is shown as follows, it looks successful.
# result of building the cv_bridge
Starting >>> cv_bridge
Finished <<< cv_bridge [10.4s]                       

Summary: 1 package finished [10.7s]

However, the cv_bridge package doesn't appear in my Ros 2 package list. When I typed ros2 pkg list | grep cv_bridge, nothing happens. So I would like to ask what is the correct way to add the package.
I know it might be easier using sudo apt to install with the deb package. But I need to install it in my home directory, rather than the global environment like opt.

After compiling, you have to 'source' the setup.bash file in the install directory.
I.e. go into your the folder where you did the colcon build and then run:
source install/setup.bash


It works! Thanks for your reply.

You will have to source each time you open a new terminal, or add the command to your .bashrc file.

Got it, thanks!
